# Run Code Compare as standalone when doing comparison from within Visual Studio 12

Tags: tfs, codecompare

How do I run Code Compare separately (Standalone) when doing code comparison in TFS before checking in code changes. Right now the code compare window opens up inside the Visual studio environment.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out myself :) Confusing part was "from command line"

```
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Use StandAlone application from command line by default
```

Answer (score 0):

you searched for this tool? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dace3633-0b51-4629-85d4-c59cdce5bb3b/
should be standalone ;) The code compare in visual studio itself cannot be ran standalone as far as I know.

Comment: This is what I have installed. but when I do the code comparison from within Visual studio, it open the comparison window inside the Visual studio . I want to do the comparison in seperate window (Exe)